# No lazy loading for Resource Dictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, initialization, lazy-loading, eager-loading

is there a possibility in WPF / XAML to eager load resource dictionaries? I have a resource dictionary defined in my XAML:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
    <local:SomeConverter x:Key="SomeConverter"/>
    <local:SomeView x:Key="SomeView" />
</s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
```

I need these resources before the loaded event occurs - is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you place you ResourceDictionaries BEFORE you create the control then you should be fine. If you are REALLY eager then put your Resources in the App.xaml file

Comment: Thanks. Sounds promising, unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to put the dictionary before the actual control in XAML, since every XAML is allowed only one root element. Am I missing something here? Putting it in the App.xaml seems dirty, it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Im pretty sure the problem lies somewhere else. I place all my Styles in App.xaml and NEVER in Windows/Pages/Controls. Yes it does have only 1 root element but WPF is smart enough to load it correctly in App.xaml